# Explanation for the definition of monomials as products of products

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition

I'm attempting to learn abstract algebra, so I've been reading these [notes by John Perry](http://www.math.usm.edu/perry/old_classes/mat423fa11/notes_20aug2011.pdf). Monomials are defined (p. 23) as
$$
\mathbb{M} = \{x^a : a \in \mathbb{N}\} \hspace{10mm} \text{or} \hspace{10mm} \mathbb{M}_n = \left\{\prod_{i=1}^m{\left( x_1^{a_1}x_2^{a_2} \dotsm x_n^{a_n} \right)} : m,a_1,a_2,\dotsc,a_n \in \mathbb{N}\ \right\}
$$
which makes sense. I understand the non-commutativity of matrix multiplication, but I don't understand this statement (p. 24):

> So multiplication of monomials should not in general be considered commutative. This is, in fact, why we defined $\mathbb{M}_{n}$ as a product of products, rather than combining the factors into one product in the form $x_1^{a_1}x_2^{a_2} \dotsm x_n^{a_n}$.

I'm missing the connection between the non-commutativity of multiplication and the construction of the monomial definition.

Comment: I don't like this definition -- it is too ambiguous. For instance, for $n = 2$, are $(x_1^2 x_2^0) (x_1^1 x_2^0)$ and $(x_1^3 x_2^0)$ the same monomial? (Yes, but the definition creates the impression that they are distinct.) Pretending that indeterminates are "unknown quantities" isn't very precise either -- it is an intuition, but "formal symbols" (i.e., objects not in the base ring) fits it better. The indeterminate $x$ in the polynomial ring $\mathbb{F}_2\left[x\right]$ is not an "unknown element of $\mathbb{F}_2$"; otherwise, the polynomials $x^2-x$ and $0$ would be identical.

Comment: Also, $x_1^{a_1} x_2^{a_2} \cdots x_n^{a_n}$ should be $x_1^{a_{i,1}} x_2^{a_{i,2}} \cdots x_n^{a_{i,n}}$. This is corrected in a newer version of the notes: http://www.math.usm.edu/perry/old_classes/mat424sp13/complete.pdf .

Comment: Aha! Thank you. This was exactly my source of confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the commutative case, $x_1x_2x_1$ is equal to $x_1^2x_2$. However, in the non-commutative case, they need not be equal. Suppose now that we're in a situation where $x_1x_2x_1 \neq x_1^2x_2$. If the set of monomials had not been defined as products of products, then $x_1x_2x_1$ would not be considered a monomial as it is not of the form $x_1^{a_1}x_2^{a_2}\dots x_n^{a_n}$.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I think the source of my misunderstanding is a misinterpretation of capital-pi notation. I thought $\prod_{i=1}^m{\left( x_1^{a_1}x_2^{a_2} \dotsm x_n^{a_n} \right)} = \left( x_1^{a_1}x_2^{a_2} \dotsm x_n^{a_n} \right)^m$, but this does not seem to be the case.

Comment: Actually I interpreted the notation correctly. The monomial definition simply had a typo, as pointed out by darij above.

Comment: @BenSimmons: Sorry, I should have pointed out that there was a typo first. I effectively answered the question under the assumption that $\mathbb{M}_n$ was defined as in the new version of notes found in darij grinberg's comment above.